# Can you index a transformation e.g. event_timestamp::date

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-timestamp

I'm preparing an 'ideal' events fact table to hand off to our engineers to build. My question is, if we have an event timestamp field `event_time` and I want to index the dates only, is it possible to index `event_time::date` or must I request a separate date field based on the event_time for indexing purposes?

Comment: You can do `create index on ideal ((event_time::date));`. Whether it will be a benefit is something you would have to test.  My suspicion is not, as querying on the `timestamp` means querying on the `date` anyway.

Comment: You can create a secondary [auto generated] column for it or you can index the expression as shown by @AdrianKlavier. However, if you index the expression, make sure your queries use the exact same expression in the search predicates. Slight variations could prevent the index to be used.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the info

Comment: Why have you got a timestamp in your fact table - how are you linking it to a dimension table?